# show button when fields return from js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular to show a form which have 2 fields that are being assign via db query (user and room) and a submit button (which doesn't need any db operation to load).

what happens, when I write this code below, is that the button is being shown instantly (since it doesn't depened on anything) and the fields: randomName, and randomRoom take a bit time to load since they need db operation.

what I want is to show all the form (button and fields at the same time).

I need something of when-fields-are-loaded-from-db ---> load them with button...

Thanks

```
        <button type="button"  ng-click="randomRoomButtonClass=true;getRandomRoom()">Random conversation!</button>
                <br>        
                    <br>
                    <li ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass"  style="list-style: none;">{{randomName}}</li>
                    <li ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass"  style="list-style: none;">{{randomRoom}}</li>
                    <button type="button"  ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass" ng-click="enterRoom({name: randomName,room: randomRoom})">Enter!
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the html in a div using an ng-if directive. The timeout is used for proof of concept.  This would be in your callback instead, minus the $timeout.

https://jsfiddle.net/53j7749e/

Angular

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.randomName = 'Yo';
    $scope.randomRoom = 'Hey';
  }, 2000);
}
```

HTML

```
<span ng-if="!randomName">Loading...</span>
<div ng-if="randomName">
  <button type="button" ng-click="randomRoomButtonClass=true;getRandomRoom()">Random conversation!</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li>{{randomName}}</li>
  <li>{{randomRoom}}</li>
  <button type="button" ng-click="enterRoom({name: randomName,room: randomRoom})">Enter!
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A work around is using a delay. You can try using the ng-Show event:

```
<button type="button"  ng-click="randomRoomButtonClass=true;getRandomRoom()" >Random conversation!</button>
        <br>        
            <br>
            <li ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass" ng-change="setDelay()" style="list-style: none;">{{randomName}}</li>
            <li ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass" ng-change="setDelay()" style="list-style: none;">{{randomRoom}}</li>
            <button type="button"  ng-if="randomRoomButtonClass" ng-click="enterRoom({name: randomName,room: randomRoom})"  ng-show="delay">Enter!
            </button>
```

You can add a delay function within your controller.

```
$scope.setDelay = function(){
    $scope.delay = true;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.delay = false;
    }, 100);
};
```

Read More:
[Can ng-show directive be used with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842299/can-ng-show-directive-be-used-with-a-delay)